# Homecontroller does not exist error in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

> Class App\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist

**HomeController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::paginate(10);
        return view ('pages.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }

    public function show($slug)
    {
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        return view ('pages.show', compact('post')); 
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/post/{slug}', 'HomeController@show')->name('post.show');
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>'Admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
    Route::resource('/categories', 'CategoriesController');
    Route::resource('/tags', 'TagsController');
    Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController');
    Route::resource('/posts', 'PostsController');
});
```

At the beginning a new authorization controller appeared, I turned off the KG and removed

Comment: Did you try  "composer dump-autoload"  ?

Comment: thx i dont know about this command

Comment: did it fix the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Run this command to clear all compiled files:

```sh
php artisan clear-compiled
```

See more as this commands here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

In some cases adding the controller directory resolves this issue. Please check the controller directory and make changes according to that.

Normally it is **App\Http\Controllers**
if so, then you can try with changing the route code to the following:

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index');
Route::get('/post/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@show')->name('post.show');
```

check your controller directory.